# How to make curl available in Docker image based java:8-jdk-alpine and keep the image clean?

Tags: java, docker, docker-java

We are having java code that runs curl command to fetch the some result.

We have built a jar file and the jar file executes fine

Now, when we try to dokerize the java program (using jar) and run the application in docker we get this error:

```
errorjava.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.ps.api.common.CoreAPI_Spec.executeCoreAPI(CoreAPI_Spec.java:295)
    at com.ps.api.common.CoreAPI_Spec.getAccessTokens(CoreAPI_Spec.java:319)
```

Dockerfile used :

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER niro;

# Install prerequisites
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
curl

FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /Users/******/Desktop/CoreAPI_Jar

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD *******_Automation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar ******_Automation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["java", "-jar", "******-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"]
```

Answer (score 173):

The Java base image you are using is Alpine Linux one and curl package also needs to be downloaded from there. Here is Dockerfile I have used for Production deployments.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

RUN apk add --update \
    curl \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

---

## **Update 05/2019**

As of Alpine Linux 3.3 there exists a new `--no-cache` option for `apk`. It allows users to install packages with an index that is updated and used on-the-fly and not cached locally:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
    
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
```

This avoids the need to use `--update` and remove `/var/cache/apk/*` when done installing packages.

Reference -
https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/usage.md and Thank you @Daniel for the comment.

Comment: Recent versions of apk support a more concise syntax: apk --no-cache add curl

Comment: No matter I tried it keeps saying "/bin/sh: curl: not found"

Comment: network error (check Internet connection and firewall)

Answer (score 11):

Your example dockerfile contains multiple `FROM` statements. This is valid but as the documentation says each `FROM` clears the state from previous [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds). And so the fresh installed curl is wiped after the second `FROM`.

Comment: Markus you are not right. With docker 17.05 there is a major change. Please adjust your answer. [Ref](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was not aware of that feature. :)

Comment: Sure, no problem, and the answer is correct now - `curl` will not be available as its wiped out.

Comment: Curl is not unavailable because it has been "wiped out", curl just is not part of Alpine by default.

Comment: @CaptainMan: But it is going to be installed in the Dockerfile and will be wiped after the second FROM statement.

Comment: @Markus The build's first stage using Ubuntu should still produce an image that has curl installed though.

Comment: Yes, but it is wiped after the second FROM switching to Alpine. See [reference link](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) in first comment.

Comment: Unfortunately the laptop I am on right now can't run Docker (Windows 7) so I cannot test, but I could've sworn running `docker images` would show the intermediate stages as unnamed images. Maybe this is just an issue of word usage though. When I see "wiped out" I think deleted, but as I'm saying I don't think it is. That said, the *state* of the build is wiped, but it seems like a moot point to mention it when talking about installed packages as opposed to things like `WORKDIR` or `ADD` -- especially since Ubuntu and Alpine don't use the same package manager so the commands would be different.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Command -- > `apk add curl`

Answer (score -8):

Most languages have readily available HTTP clients these days; you should almost never be calling out to `curl` from a program in a language more sophisticated than a shell script.  [java.net.URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) has been a part of Java since Java 1.0 and (without knowing why you're trying to shell out for this) it's almost definitely the right tool here.

Assuming you control the `executeCoreAPI` method from your backtrace, you should change it to use the built-in Java HTTP client, and just delete all of the Dockerfile parts that try to install `curl`.

Comment: Sometimes you don't want to build a product to see what response the webserver is returning.  The question is about installing curl, this answer isn't one.

Comment: i.e. curl is usefull to implement a quick healthcheck for swarm.