# Java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory on executing curl in java

Tags: java, docker, curl, x509certificate

I'm using curl for certificate-based/x509 authentication
`

```
String command = "curl --cert " +certificateFilePath+" --key "+ certificateKeyFilePath+" --insecure "+authUrl;

          ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command); 
            Process p;
            try
            {
                p = process.start();
                 BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            builder.append(line);
                            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    }
                    String result = builder.toString();
                    System.out.print("result ------------------:  "+result);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

`

but getting exception `

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

`

given that the application and auth service are running inside docker-container on Ubuntu and works fine when I manually go inside the application docker-container and execute the above curl command.
Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make curl available in Docker image based java:8-jdk-alpine and keep the image clean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51192713/how-to-make-curl-available-in-docker-image-based-java8-jdk-alpine-and-keep-the)

Answer (score 0):

From process builder docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

The proper way to do it is to call it with the parameters passed as separate strings otherwise it won't work. Also in order to run system commands like  `curl` in linux or `dir` in windows you need to call the command interpreter - sh for linux. So your command should become something like:

```
ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c","curl","--cert", certificationPath......);
```

Or you can try:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);  //Here you pass the whole command as a string
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to run a JVM under root or with sudo java....
It may not have enough permissions for JVM.